# Issues while eMMC partitioned using sfdisk

Tags: linux, shell-script, udev, fdisk, sfdisk

I am writing firmware(MLO,u-boot.img, uImage(ver 3.12), dtb, rootfs.tar.gz) programming script for am335x based custom board.
Rootfile system is to be put onto the eMMC. Firmware programming script runs as the one of the init script from the nfsroot folder when board boots for the first time at programming station.

Basically script
1. Partitions the eMMC and
2. writes MLO, u-boot.img, uImage, dtb in the raw area of the first partition and
3. Then formats the other partitions as ext4 and
4. mounts ext4 partitions and extacts the rootfs.tar.gz.

Now there are two issues with the script and one with backup kernel memory area.

**Script issues**

1. I am not able create more than 7 partition(including logical partitions), though sfdisk creates the partitions device files related to partition is not available in /dev directory

Here is sfdisk command i used

```
#Partition emmc 
sfdisk -D -H 255 -S 63 -C 467 /dev/mmcblk0 -uM << EOF
,32,C,*
,200,L
,200,L
,,E
,100,L
,60,L
,200,L
;1269,L
;
EOF
```

When i list the partition fdisk/sfdisk reports 8 partitions but i don't see partition files related to 8th partition.

Here is fdisk output for the same,

```
# fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0

Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 3841 MB, 3841982464 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 467 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

        Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks  Id System
/dev/mmcblk0p1   *           1           5       40131   c Win95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2               6          31      208845  83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p3              32          57      208845  83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p4              58         467     3293325   5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5              58          70      104391  83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p6              71          78       64228+ 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p7              79         104      208813+ 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p8             105         266     1301233+ 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p9             267         467     1614501  83 Linux
```

2. Some times after partitioning eMMC device files(/dev/mmcblk0p2, /dev/mmcblk0p3 etc) doesn't appear and mkfs utility fails to format the partition and firmware flashing fails.

**eMMC memory issue**

First partition of the eMMC is of type "Win95 FAT32 (LBA)"
We are not formatting this partition and using it as raw.

There 3 copies of MLO, 2 copies of u-boot.img, uImage and dtb in the that partition.

Now after trying multiple time flashing using dd, uImage first copy memory area is corrupted and board complains the image in that partition is corrupted.

Now if eMMC is having controller handling wear leveling and error correction mechanism then how memory area where kernel is stored is corrupted?

Any suggestions/ideas/pointers to any of the mentioned problem?